# MVC DB Migration: The method or operation is not implemented?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I have successfully created an InventoryTracking Application with MVC5/EF6 using Code-First Migrations to fill in my LocalDB file for some testing Data. I am now attempting to modify the app to make use of an Oracle DB in which I have created the same tables as what reside in my LocalDB file.

After A LOT of digging around, I got `Oracle Developer Tools` downloaded for my VS2013 (Zip File: `ODTwithODAC121021`). Then using NUGET I installed `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` so it could work with EF6 (Apparently - as of a year ago by most articles - `Oracle.DataAccess` did not work with EF6 only EF5).

My **Web.Config** is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="Default" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_123)(PORT=1234)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=hostprd)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));MIN POOL SIZE=3;PASSWORD=123_syst;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=Userid; Connection Lifetime=16; Connection Timeout=8" />
    <!--<add name="InventoryTrackerContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\InventoryTrackerDBDev-4.mdf;Initial Catalog=InventoryTrackerDBDev-4;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="DefaultConnection" value="Default" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="InventoryTracker" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- Active Directory Authentication - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" /><add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" /><add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" /></httpModules>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="GridMvc" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
      <!--
      http errors allows us to override default errors.
      errorMode="Custom" means that IIS will always serve our custom pages.
      if you want to see details while in develoment mode, set to DetailedLocalOnly.
      for this demo, we have it set to Custom.
    -->
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
          <remove statusCode="404" />
          <remove statusCode="500" />
          <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
          <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Error" />
      </httpErrors>  
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
      <remove name="BundleModule" />
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" /><add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" /><add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" /></modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext, InventoryTracker">
        <databaseInitializer type="InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryInitializer, InventoryTracker" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <elmah>
    <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
  </elmah><location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Then in my MVC5 project I have a folder called `DAL` wherein I have 2 files:

**InventoryTrackerContext.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using InventoryTracker.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using InventoryTracker.DAL;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Configuration;

namespace InventoryTracker.DAL
{
    public class InventoryTrackerContext : DbContext
    {
        public InventoryTrackerContext()
            //: base("InventoryTrackerContext")
            : base( new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString), true)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<INV_Assets> INV_Assets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Models> INV_Models { get;set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Manufacturers> INV_Manufacturers { get;set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Types> INV_Types { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Locations> INV_Locations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Vendors> INV_Vendors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Statuses> INV_Statuses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
             modelBuilder.Entity<INV_Assets>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<InventoryTracker.Models.INV_Owners> INV_Owners { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<InventoryTracker.Models.INV_AssetsHistory> INV_AssetsHistory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**InventoryInitializer**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using InventoryTracker.Models;
using InventoryTracker.DAL;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace InventoryTracker.DAL
{
    public class InventoryInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<InventoryTrackerContext>
    {
        InventoryTrackerContext context = new InventoryTrackerContext();

        protected override void Seed(InventoryTrackerContext context)
        {
            List<INV_Locations> invLocs = getLocations();
            invLocs.ForEach(s => context.INV_Locations.Add(s));
            List<INV_Manufacturers> invManufacturers = getManufacturers();
            invManufacturers.ForEach(s => context.INV_Manufacturers.Add(s));
            List<INV_Models> invModels = getModels();
            invModels.ForEach(s => context.INV_Models.Add(s));
            List<INV_Statuses> invStatuses = getStatuses();
            invStatuses.ForEach(s => context.INV_Statuses.Add(s));
            List<INV_Types> invTypes = getTypes();
            invTypes.ForEach(s => context.INV_Types.Add(s));
            List<INV_Vendors> invVendors = getVendors();
            invVendors.ForEach(s => context.INV_Vendors.Add(s));

            List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
            invAssets.ForEach(s => context.INV_Assets.Add(s));

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // SEED CODE THAT DOESN'T APPEAR TO RUN? THIS FILE IS REFERENCED IN WEB.CONFIG
    }
}
```

Then in my `Migrations` folder I have a file called **Configuration.cs**:

```
namespace InventoryTracker.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Globalization;
    using InventoryTracker.Models;
    using InventoryTracker.DAL;
    using WebMatrix.WebData;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(InventoryTracker.DAL.InventoryTrackerContext context)
        {
List<INV_Locations> invLocs = getLocations();
            context.INV_Locations.AddRange(invLocs);
            context.SaveChanges();
            List<INV_Manufacturers> invManufacturers = getManufacturers();
            context.INV_Manufacturers.AddRange(invManufacturers);
            context.SaveChanges();
            List<INV_Models> invModels = getModels();
            context.INV_Models.AddRange(invModels);
            context.SaveChanges();
            List<INV_Statuses> invStatuses = getStatuses();
            context.INV_Statuses.AddRange(invStatuses);

            context.SaveChanges();

            List<INV_Types> invTypes = getTypes();
            context.INV_Types.AddRange(invTypes);
            context.SaveChanges();
            List<INV_Vendors> invVendors = getVendors();
            context.INV_Vendors.AddRange(invVendors);

            context.SaveChanges();

            List<INV_Assets> invAssets = getAssets();
            context.INV_Assets.AddRange(invAssets);

            List<INV_AssetsHistory> invAssetsHistory = getAssetHistories();
            context.INV_AssetsHistory.AddRange(invAssetsHistory);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Various GET() Code, this is where the Seeding DOES Occur as opposed to file above.
}
```

When I had my connection string defined for `InventoryTrackerContext` inside the **Web.config**, I could simply create new migrations (`add-migration InitialCreate`) and then run (`update-database`) to seed my LocalDB file with the data I've specified in my **Configuration.cs**.

Now that I'm attempting to use my `ORACLE` connection `["Default"]` and access via the similar context, I'm having issues. I've created a new Migration, but when I try to run (`update-database`) I receive the following:

```
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201503251604557_InitialCreate].
Applying explicit migration: 201503251604557_InitialCreate.
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateProcedureOperation createProcedureOperation)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , OracleMigrationSqlGenerator , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , OracleMigrationSqlGenerator , Object )
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleMigrationSqlGenerator.<GenerateStatements>b__2(Object op)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EntityUtils.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleMigrationSqlGenerator.GenerateStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

I also get the same error message on a `db.Table.ToList()` if I try to run the application...?

Comment: Take a look at what's in the Up() method of the migration or you could generate a script (update-database -Script) and try it in SQL Developer and see what Oracle doesn't like. I ran into this with some datatype mismatches.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Because I got this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your app is following asp.net Core 2.0 code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

My issue happened in my program.cs file.